# Javascript: empty string

Tags: string

How to check if a string is empty in Javascript?

I already used this condition `if (res32.trim == "")` and `if (res32 == "")` and didn't work.

res32 is a `var res32 = str.subtring(111,112)` and can have the following values: spaces, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

```
if (res32 == " ") {
    if (res21 == 000000) {
        document.write("<td bgcolor=#99FF00><font face=Verdana color=#FFFFFF  size=1>true</font></td></tr>
    }
} else {
  if (res32 == 0 || res32 ==1 || res32 ==4 || res32 ==5 || res32 ==6 || res32 ==7) {
      if (res21 > 0){
          document.write("<td bgcolor=#99FF00><font face=Verdana color=#FFFFFF  size=1>true</font></td></tr>");
      } else {
          document.write("<td bgcolor=#FF0000><font face=Verdana color=#FFFFFF size=1>false</font></td></tr>");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log(string)` to print out what the value is it contains and then check for that...? By the way, use the <code> button on your markup field when making this. This looks rubbish.

Comment: it should be res32.trim() == "" ... unless you just left of the () when typing up your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `.value`:

```js
function checkValue(){
  
  var res32 = document.getElementById('res32');

if (res32.value == "" || res32.value == null){

  alert('The text field is empty.');
  
  }else{

  alert('The text field is not empty.');
  
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="res32">

<input type="button" onclick="checkValue()" value="Check if the input field is null.">
```